# How can you simplify $\arcsin(\cos(x)\sin(x))$

Tags: trigonometry

I was poking around in Desmos and discovered the interesting function $\arcsin(\sin(x)\cos(x))$, and I was wondering if this could be simplified. The function $\frac{π}{6}\sin(2x+π)+\frac{π}{2}$ is extremely close, but not exactly.

Comment: Why do you say $\frac{π}{6}\sin(2x+π)+\frac{π}{2}$, which looks strange (for example when $x=0$) rather than $\frac{π}{6}\sin(2x)$?

Comment: Both functions would then be cyclic with period $\pi$, and are clearly equal when $x$ is a multiple of $\frac \pi 4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, so $\arcsin(\cos (x)\sin(x))=\arcsin(\frac 12 \sin(2x))$.  For small $x$, say within $(-0.5,0.5)$ this is very close to $x$ as shown below (note the scale on $y$). The Taylor series starts $x-\frac{x^3}2-\frac {x^5}8$[image]